# Execute instructions later

Tags: solidity, events, timers

I'm looking to create a function that executes instructions in a time frame.
For example I want to call a function that will change my variable in 50 seconds.

I have searched but I saw that I need to import something else. Is there any way to do this directly in solidity?

Answer (score 2):

No. A smart contract can't "wait" (make time pass), nor execute itself after some time, nor execute another smart contract at another time. You need some script or bot or cron job outside of the blockchain to achieve this.